# Set Selected Dropdown Value in PDF from FDF File

Tags: php, pdftk, fdf

I have an editable PDF with defined fields that I have been saving to using a FDF file with PDFtk.  All works fine, except I now I need to select a dropdown value and cannot see how to select one.  Here's the field data extracted from PDFtk.

```
FieldType: Choice
FieldName: Dropdown1
FieldFlags: 131072
FieldValue:  
FieldValueDefault:  
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption:  
FieldStateOption: Active
FieldStateOption: Active - Works as Needed
FieldStateOption: Casual
...
```

Here's the snippet of the FDF I have created:

```
<</T(Text Field 11)/V(Good)>>
<</T(Dropdown1)/Opt [(Active - Works as Needed)]>>
<</T(Text Field 23)/V(15000.00)>>
```

I have tried:

```
<</T(Dropdown1)/Opt [(Active - Works as Needed)]>>
<</Opt [(Active - Works as Needed)]>>
```

But when I load the PDF, the dropdown hasn't a value selected.  What should the line look like so the saved PDF will have the proper value (FieldStateOption) selected?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
<</T(Text Field 11)/V(Good)>>
<</T(Dropdown1) /V (Active - Works as Needed) /Opt [(Active - Works as Needed)]>>
<</T(Text Field 23)/V(15000.00)>>
```

You just have to set a `/V` (value) with the same text.

Comment: We ended up getting a different PDF and got it worked out, but thanks!